# Quantifying reads mapping to multiple loci

Tags: rna-seq, sam, samtools, star, pysam

I have been using [STAR](https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR) for our RNA-Seq samples. The `final.out` log file reports percentage of uniquely mapped reads along with percentage of reads that map to `multiple loci` (less than or equal to 10) and percentage of reads mapping to `too many loci` (greater than 10). However, I want to break down the `multiple loci` part to individual counts: Reads mapping to 2 locations, 3 locations, 4 locations .. 10 locations.

The `NH` tag seems to be used by `STAR`. However a naive read counting approach results in it reporting more number of reads than total reads.

For example, my `final.out` looks like this:

```
   Mapping speed, Million of reads per hour |       1403.36

                      Number of input reads |       53015978
                  Average input read length |       26
                                UNIQUE READS:
               Uniquely mapped reads number |       368916
                    Uniquely mapped reads % |       0.70%
                      Average mapped length |       26.45
                   Number of splices: Total |       1057
        Number of splices: Annotated (sjdb) |       0
                   Number of splices: GT/AG |       802
                   Number of splices: GC/AG |       1
                   Number of splices: AT/AC |       0
           Number of splices: Non-canonical |       254
                  Mismatch rate per base, % |       0.31%
                     Deletion rate per base |       0.00%
                    Deletion average length |       1.45
                    Insertion rate per base |       0.00%
                   Insertion average length |       1.00
                         MULTI-MAPPING READS:
    Number of reads mapped to multiple loci |       45766732
         % of reads mapped to multiple loci |       86.33%
    Number of reads mapped to too many loci |       3757890
         % of reads mapped to too many loci |       7.09%
                              UNMAPPED READS:
   % of reads unmapped: too many mismatches |       0.00%
             % of reads unmapped: too short |       5.89%
                 % of reads unmapped: other |       0.00%
```

Counting histogram of number of positions a read maps to using `pysam`:

```
def get_reads_hist(bam): 
    bam = pysam.AlignmentFile(bam, 'rb')
    counts = Counter()
    for query in bam.fetch():
        nh_count = Counter(dict(query.get_tags())['NH'])
        counts += nh_count            
    return counts
```

results in

```
Counter({1: 330606,
     2: 86772164,
     3: 329,
     4: 38083,
     5: 31,
     6: 1094,
     7: 129,
     8: 50,
     10: 50})
```

The count `1` reads are fine even though they do not match the counts in `final.out` file since I am counting a certain category of reads (say those mapping to `tRNA` only), but the reads mapping to 2 locations are highly overestimated. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost had the correct python code already, you just need to filter out secondary alignments:

```
def get_reads_hist(bam): 
    bam = pysam.AlignmentFile(bam, 'rb')
    counts = Counter()
    for query in bam.fetch():
        if query.is_secondary:
            continue
        nh_count = Counter(dict(query.get_tags())['NH'])
        counts += nh_count            
    return counts
```